# CSS using filter & z-index properties together

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-filters

I Have a problem with css filter.
I have an `<img>` element that is for my posts background image, this is css code for that element:

```css
.post-background
{
 height: 190px;
 margin-bottom: -190px;
 object-fit: cover;
 object-position: 0 -90px;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

Now, I want to make that image darker with `filter: brightness(50%);` but when I set this property, my post content (called `.post-front`) disappears from the page.

Comment: you can set "position: absolute" to class post-front,
that will appear content in case of hover

Comment: @NavinGelot Oh! I didn't think it would be so easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hover `.post-background` image when you `hover post-item`
just add following class and modify `.post-front`

```
.post-item:hover .post-background {
  filter: brightness(50%);
}

.post-front {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 190px 1fr 100px;
}
```

remove following changes:

```
.post-background:hover {
    filter: brightness(50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I don't know your whole code, so It is hard to guess what went wrong in your code. this is an example of how to use hover with filter.

```css
.mybox{
  height:150px;
  width:250px;
  border:1px solid;
   position: relative;
}
.img{
   width: 100%;
  height:150px;
   object-fit: cover;
}
.middle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
.textbox{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
.mybox:hover .img{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(50%) !important;
    filter: brightness(50%) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="mybox">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.hd-freewallpapers.com/latest-wallpapers/desktop-image-of-a-parrot-wallpaper.jpg" alt="Card image">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="textbox">anyThing</div>
  </div>
</div>
```